# Error adding lwjgl-opengles to gradle

Tags: android, gradle, opengl-es, android-gradle-plugin, lwjgl

I want to use lwjgl-opengles in my android application.
When I add in Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengles:3.1.0'
}
```

I get the following error when compiling:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/INDEX.LIST
    File1: /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lwjgl/lwjgl-opengles/3.1.0/34022551efca063f31282f9952c29bdd41cb3c15/lwjgl-opengles-3.1.0.jar
    File2: /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lwjgl/lwjgl/3.1.0/fae7a04425666311d5dfe5ef7d89021ca0308d8d/lwjgl-3.1.0.jar
```

How to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add exclude to your gradle

```
android {    
   packagingOptions { 
     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
 }
}
```